# Display a window to obtain user input

Tags: java, swing, frame

I'm new to programming with Java.

I have these two small projects.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class tutorial {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("hello");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(label);

        JButton button = new JButton("Hello again");
        panel.add(button);
    }
}
```

and this one:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int age;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How old are you?");
        age = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (age<18) 
        {
            System.out.println("Hi youngster!");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Hello mature!");
        }
    }

}
```

How can I add the second code to the first one, so that the user will see a window that says 'How old are you' and they can type their age.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider doing what I did when wanting to advance in my understanding of Java and Swing -- check out the tutorials. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info). Much luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of all the things you wanted because it was undefined, but as I far as I understand, you wanted a JFrame containing an input field, in which you will be able to input values and display the appropriate answer.
I also suggest you read tutorial , but don't hesitate if you have question.
I hope it's a bit close to what you wanted.

```
package example.tutorial;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Tutorial extends JPanel {
    private static final String YOUNG_RESPONSE = "Hi youngster!";
    private static final String ADULT_RESPONSE = "Hello mature!";
    private static final String INVALID_AGE = "Invalid age!";

    private static final int MIN_AGE = 0;
    private static final int MAX_AGE = 100;

    private static JTextField ageField;
    private static JLabel res;

    private Tutorial() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel("How old are you ? ");
        northPanel.add(label);

        ageField = new JTextField(15);
        northPanel.add(ageField);
        add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();  
        JButton btn = new JButton("Hello again");
        btn.addActionListener(new BtnListener());
        centerPanel.add(btn);

        res = new JLabel();
        res.setVisible(false);
        centerPanel.add(res);

        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.add(new Tutorial());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private static class BtnListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String content = ageField.getText();
            int age = -1;
            try{
                age = Integer.parseInt(content);
                if(isValid(age)) {
                    res.setText(age < 18 ? YOUNG_RESPONSE : ADULT_RESPONSE);
                } else {
                    res.setText(INVALID_AGE);
                }
                if(!res.isVisible())
                    res.setVisible(true);
            } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                res.setText("Wrong input");
            }
        }

        private boolean isValid(int age) {
            return age > MIN_AGE && age < MAX_AGE;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> so that the user will see a window that says 'How old are you' and they can type their age.

The easiest way to start would be to use a `JOptionPane`. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for examples and explanation.

Don't forget to look at the table of contents for other Swing related topics for basic information about Swing.

Answer (score 2):

You will need an input field to get the text and then add an `ActionListener` to the button which contains the logic that is performed when the button is pressed.

I modified your code to implement what you described:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class tutorial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("hello");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(label);

        final JTextField input = new JTextField(5); // The input field with a width of 5 columns
        panel.add(input);

        JButton button = new JButton("Hello again");
        panel.add(button);

        final JLabel output = new JLabel(); // A label for your output
        panel.add(output);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // The action listener which notices when the button is pressed
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String inputText = input.getText();
                int age = Integer.parseInt(inputText);
                if (age < 18) {
                    output.setText("Hi youngster!");
                } else {
                    output.setText("Hello mature!");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In that example we don't validate the input. So if the input is not an Integer `Integer.parseInt` will throw an exception. Also the components are not arranged nicely. But to keep it simple for the start that should do it. :)

Comment: All I see is a window with 'hello'

Comment: @user3024879 Did you copy the whole code? To me it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

it's not an easy question since you are working on command line in one example, and in a Swing GUI in the other.

Here's a working example, i've commented here and there. 
This is no where near java best practises and it misses a lot of validation (just see what happens when you enter a few letters or nothing in the textfield.

Also please ignore the setLayout(null) and setBounds() statements, it's just a simple example not using any layout managers.

I hope my comments will help you discovering java!

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

//You'll need to implement the ActionListener to listen to buttonclicks
public class Age implements ActionListener{

    //Declare class variables so you can use them in different functions
    JLabel label;
    JTextField textfield;

    //Don't do al your code in the static main function, instead create an instance
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Age();
    }

    // this constructor is called when you create a new Age(); like in the main function above.
    public Age()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0,0,300,300);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        label = new JLabel("hello");
        label.setBounds(5,5,100,20);

        // a JTextfield allows the user to edit the text in the field.
        textfield = new JTextField();
        textfield.setBounds(5,30,100,20);

        JButton button = new JButton("Hello again");
        button.setBounds(130,30,100,20);
        // Add this instance as the actionlistener, when the button is clicked, function actionPerformed will be called.
        button.addActionListener(this);

        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(textfield);
        panel.add(button);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //Required function actionPerformed for ActionListener. When the button is clicked, this function is called.
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // get the text from the input.
        String text = textfield.getText();

        // parse the integer value from the string (! needs validation for wrong inputs !)
        int age = Integer.parseInt(text);
        if (age<18) 
        {
            //instead of writing out, update the text of the label.
            label.setText("Hi youngster!");
        }
        else 
        {
            label.setText("Hello mature!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3024879: but take this answer with a grain of salt. His code shows use of the `null` layout and `setBounds(...)`. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one

Comment: Thanks for the reply, since he told us he is new to Java programming, I tried to show him some extra basic features, like instanciation, implementing an ActionListener, and variable scope. As said in my post, this is no where near java best practises. My experience with the Swing toolkit is limited and old, so I would trust Hovercraft on this and look into the LayoutManagers if you want to do some serious GUI programming. Also the code could be much better with proper use of inherentance and the input needs validation. (google these, if you don't know!)